# Transform a 2D nested list, which includes other data types, to integers in Python

Tags: python, list, integer

I am new to the coding/ computer science world and trying to learn Python. If anyone could help with the below. I am trying to iterate through the two dimensional list and convert all the strings, which are numbers, and convert them into integers. I am getting an error when using the int() method due to the fact that some of the strings are names. Any help would be appreciated.

My 2D nested array is;

```
examRes = [['joe bloggs', '45', '46', '52', '83'],
           ['bobby uncle', '52', '45', '85', '63'],
           ['luke van', '69', '48', '45', '22']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something along the following lines:

```
examRes = [['joe bloggs', '45', '46', '52', '83'],['bobby uncle', '52', '45', '85', '63'],['luke van', '69', '48', '45', '22']]

for lst in examRes:
    for i, val in enumerate(lst):
        if val.isdigit():
            lst[i] = int(val)
```

More generally, if you had floats or negative ints, you could just do:

```
        try:
            lst[i] = int(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

in the inner loop. In this particular case, however, where you know the positions of your names and grades, you can simply use slice assignment:

```
for lst in examRes:
    lst[1:] = map(int, lst[1:])
```

Comment: Absolute hero. Thanks for the help.